# Spring boot app deployment error: "ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, jhipster

Can not deploy spring boot app on tomcat server(os hp-ux). Please any help

MainClass:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({LiquibaseProperties.class, ApplicationProperties.class})
public class NgrkApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NgrkApp.class);

    private final Environment env;

    public NgrkApp(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initApplication() {
        Collection<String> activeProfiles = Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles());
        if (activeProfiles.contains(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT) && activeProfiles.contains(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION)) {
            log.error("You have misconfigured your application! It should not run " +
                "with both the 'dev' and 'prod' profiles at the same time.");
        }
        if (activeProfiles.contains(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT) && activeProfiles.contains(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_CLOUD)) {
            log.error("You have misconfigured your application! It should not " +
                "run with both the 'dev' and 'cloud' profiles at the same time.");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(NgrkApp.class);
        DefaultProfileUtil.addDefaultProfile(app);
        Environment env = app.run(args).getEnvironment();
        logApplicationStartup(env);
    }

    private static void logApplicationStartup(Environment env) {
        String protocol = "http";
        if (env.getProperty("server.ssl.key-store") != null) {
            protocol = "https";
        }
        String serverPort = env.getProperty("server.port");
        String contextPath = env.getProperty("server.servlet.context-path");
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(contextPath)) {
            contextPath = "/";
        }
        String hostAddress = "localhost";
        try {
            hostAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            log.warn("The host name could not be determined, using `localhost` as fallback");
        }
        log.info("\n----------------------------------------------------------\n\t" +
                "Application '{}' is running! Access URLs:\n\t" +
                "Local: \t\t{}://localhost:{}{}\n\t" +
                "External: \t{}://{}:{}{}\n\t" +
                "Profile(s): \t{}\n----------------------------------------------------------",
            env.getProperty("spring.application.name"),
            protocol,
            serverPort,
            contextPath,
            protocol,
            hostAddress,
            serverPort,
            contextPath,
            env.getActiveProfiles());
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(NgrkApp.class);
    }

}
```

Stacktrace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class
                at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:158)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5225)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:744)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:980)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1851)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: kz.ngrk.application.NgrkApp.<init>()
                at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3109)
                at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2182)
                at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor(ReflectionUtils.java:530)
                at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:155)
                ... 12 more
```

Comment: Read exception stacktrace, it says `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: kz.ngrk.application.NgrkApp.() `. You should add default constructor to your class, Spring can't create an instance without it.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have a constructor in Ngrk.class
public NgrkApp(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

Comment: That's not default java constructor. Default means without any parameters. What version of Spring boot do you use? On Spring Boot 2 it works for me.

Comment: Also, it worse a try to add `@Autowired` to your constructor.

Comment: Most likely, the legacy servlet configuration you're trying to use requires your initializer to have a default constructor.

Comment: spring boot v.2.0.8. Constructor without parameters don't allow there

Comment: @chrylis thanks for reply. How can I fix it?

Comment: Generally speaking, just use embedded mode (the default arrangement with Boot) and cut all of this initializer business; it's not necessary and does not look like it's even really useful.

Comment: Why deploy to Tomcat ? Use your JHipster app the way it is recommended and tested by JHipster team: as an executable war/jar. You will save you a lot of headaches especially if you're a new java dev. Also have you removed the dependencies on Undertow (servlet container ermbbedded by JHipster) ?